# Ruby On Rails: Heroku run rake db:migrate failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, dbmigrate

Whenever i try to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` or want to `bundle install`

i get the following error message:

```
    PG:DuplicateObject: ERROR: constraint "fk_rails_d0c2931" 
    for relation "subscription" already exist
    : ALTER TABLE "subscriptions" ADD CONTRAINT
    "fk_railsd0c2931" FOREIGN KEY ("project_id")
```

**Edit:**

Comment: Are you migrating into a fresh db? The error indicates you are trying to create a foreign key where one already exists.

Comment: Mhm, no, actually i just wanted to deploy my application to heroku and run heroku run rake db:migrate in order to be able to use devise and so on. Its weird

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: You mean rake db:migrate? Yes, if i run rake db:migrate locally it just returns, since i have no open migration.

Comment: You can run `rake db:schema:load` on heroku then

Comment: Okay, i ran heroku rake db:schema:load and it worked. However, when i click on sign up or sign in on my application i get the error: We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.  This Error is normally gone when i run heroku run rake db:migrate. I've tried to run rake db:migrate again and it worked, however, i get still the same Error that something went wrong. Where can i see the logs? The Heroku Logs don't show anything on that problem. I see only the commit logs.

Comment: You'll have to take a look at the logs then to see what's going on.

Comment: And where do i find the logs? On heroku itself i only see my commits logs. I don't see any log particular to this problem.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: I posted the heroku log file as a new answer. Thanks already for helping out so much!

Comment: Are you trying to sign in with Google Authorisation?

The log shows `ActionView::Template::Error (undefi
    ned method 'user_omniauth_authorize_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff3700f0d78>:0x007f
    f36d84e7d0>):`